# How do I click on a ListView item and open an Activity referring to the item I clicked on?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I click on a custom listview item and everyone opens the same activity, I wanted each of the items to open a different activity.
I've tried in several ways but I'm not getting it, I'm a beginner and I do not have much knowledge, so I came here to ask for help.
It does not have to be the code ready, you can tell me something to help, it would help a lot

```
    public class artilheiros extends AppCompatActivity {

int [] Imagens = {R.drawable.arg, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil, R.drawable.chile,
          R.drawable.colombia, R.drawable.chile, R.drawable.paraguai, R.drawable.uruguai,
          R.drawable.arg, R.drawable.bolivia, R.drawable.brasil, R.drawable.chile,
          R.drawable.colombia, R.drawable.chile, R.drawable.paraguai};

String [] Nomes = {"ART 1", "ART 2", "ART 3", "ART 4", "ART 5", "ART 6", "ART 7", "ART 8",
                    "ART 9", "ART 10", "ART 11", "ART 12", "ART 13", "ART 14", "ART 15"};

String [] Times = {"TIME 1", "TIME 2", "TIME 3", "TIME 4", "TIME 5", "TIME 6", "TIME 7",
        "TIME 8", "TIME 9", "TIME 10", "TIME 11", "TIME 12", "TIME 13", "TIME 14", "TIME 15"};

String [] Gols = {"999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols",
       "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols", "999 gols"};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_artilheiros);

    final ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.listviewart);
    ListView listview2 = findViewById(R.id.listviewart);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();

    listview.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("a", 0);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            artilheiros a1 = (artilheiros) listview.getItemAtPosition(0);
            Intent it = new Intent(artilheiros.this, campeoes.class);
            it.putExtra("a1", position);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });



}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Imagens.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlistview, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewnome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewnome);
        TextView textViewtime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtime);
        TextView textViewgols = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewgols);

        imageView.setImageResource(Imagens[position]);
        textViewnome.setText(Nomes[position]);
        textViewtime.setText(Times[position]);
        textViewgols.setText(Gols[position]);



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Based on the data you are have in your arrays I cannot image the activities you wish to start could be very different from each other. A more likely scenario would be that the activities are identical and only the content would change based on the value of the item you select in your `ListView`. Secondly: Your code would be much cleaner, more maintainable and easier to implement if you would create a custom class with getters and setters for the properties (images, names, times, goals). Create a new object of the class and add that to an `ArrayList` which you pass to your `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a switch statement. Eg inside onItemClick:

```
switch (position) {
case 0: 
//start Activity 1
break;
case 1:
// start Activity 2
break;
// etc
}
```

You didn't tell us what those activities are, but a general principle is to use the least amount of activities as possible. Perhaps you can use a fragment and from onItemClick change some data for that fragment.

Comment: thanks, it worked out right here, in case it would be 6 items to open 6 activitys, 1 in each

Comment: Your welcome. In the future try to keep number of activities a minimum, since they are pretty large objects and have a lot of methods that you don't need.